# Web audio filter reduces gain rather than filtering frequencies

Tags: web-audio-api

I have the following code that wires a filter to an oscillator:

```
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

// create Oscillator node
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = 'square';   
oscillator.frequency.value = 1000; // value in hertz 
oscillator.start();

var filter = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
filter.type = 'lowpass';
filter.frequency.value = 440;

oscillator.connect(filter);
filter.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

Problem is that the filter seems to lower the gain of the oscillator rather than filtering out frequencies. What am i doing wrong here?

https://jsfiddle.net/matLkaeb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think everything is working.  Change the filter frequency to, say, 10000 and listen carefully.  Then change the frequency to 1000 and listen.  There will be a difference.  With a frequency of 440, you'll only get a single tone (mostly) from the oscillator, and the volume will be decreased because the oscillator fundamental frequency is outside the pass band of the filter.

Comment: Yes.  You're setting the filter frequency substantially BELOW the fundamental frequency of your square wave oscillator.  The result will be a 12dB/octave slope filter applied to all harmonics of the square wave - which will make it closer to a sine wave, but also radically reduces the signal level.  Try setting the osc frequency below the filter frequency.

Comment: Ah ok I see now. So if I'm building out a simple synth the filter needs to be contextual - it's filter range needs to be set in relation to the frequency of the current oscillator to be useful.